# Calculating 2 unknowns in mod 2^32 addition?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography, hash-function

My question is fairly simple.

Given equation:

**r = ( a + b + c )** mod **m**

Where **m** = 2^32, and values **r** and **a** are known values.

Assuming:

**Edit**:

**b** +  **c** < **m**

Is it possible to calculate a specific value of **b** and **c**? I've been digging into the Euclidean Algorithm/CRT, but haven't found any relation of this form that would be useful. I can pretty easily calculate the value of **b** + **c**, but I fear I'm looking at a brick wall.

Any and all help/suggestions for further reading would greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Suppose that $(b,c)$ is a solution.  Then so too is $(b-1,c+1)$ and $(b-2,c+2),\dots$.  Without more information as to the relationship between $b$ and $c$ you cannot uniquely determine them.

Comment: There are multiple valid solutions: there is no one specific value for b and c. For example, $r=3$, $a=0$, both $b=1, c=2$ and $b=2, c=1$ are valid.

Comment: Would the above edit: __b__ + __c__ < __m__ help?